# Display List of Objects in a group with self referencing foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a model which hold a collection of tasks:

```
public class model
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<task> tasks {get;set;}
}
```

the tasks is modeled like so:

```
public class task
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public byte category_id { get; set; }
    public virtual category category { get; set; }
}
```

and category is modeled like so:

```
public class category
{
    public byte category_id { get; set; }
    public string category_name { get; set; }
    public byte? parent_category_id { get; set; }
}
```

In my MVC application, I have the Details page of model, which includes the collection of tasks. I want to display the list of tasks associated with the model, grouped by Category, like so:

- Category 1

  - Task 1
  - Task 2
  - SubCategory 1
  - Task 3
  - Task 4
- Category 2

...and so on.

Some tasks are directly linked into categories, while other are housed in subcategories.

I've tried a myriad of 'Model.GroupBy(x=>x.category_id)' and have been trying to use a '.Join() if task.category.parent_category_id != null' but i'm struggling here.

What could be a better approach to doing this?  I"m suck!

Answer (score 1):

Since your data structure seems to be quite hierarchical, I would consider using a [Composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

Your tasks would then be stored within the categories and the categories could also store other categories. The model as tree root would only hold a list of parent categories instead of tasks.

In that way you could easily traverse your tree and print out the hierarchy in a recursive way.

Your composite pattern could look like:

```
// base class for composition
public abstract class Composite
{}

// category, can either hold tasks or other categories
public class Category : Composite
{
    // list of child items, either tasks or categories
    ICollection<Composite> Children { get; set;}
}

// task is a leave node in the hierarchy
public class Task : Composite
{}

// model will only hold categories
public class Model
{
    ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: So in theory, after i query all the related tasks from my task table, i would go and take that task list and put it into a separate composite pattern model?

Comment: I guess the easiest way would be to have your data already in this hierarchical structure while getting them from your DB. An OR mapper like [EF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) or [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/) could help you here to define the mapping from you tables to your object structure. But if defining this mappings would be too much overhead for you, you could also try to create this structure manually after querying all required data as you suggested.

Comment: Gotcha.  Ill have a stab at it and hopefully works out ok.  Appreciate your help!